# scrollIntoView() stops working early or doesn't work at all in most cases

Tags: jquery, html

The following is an animated arrow that grows and shrinks. That is what a user clicks on to move down the page to the youtube video.

```
<!-- SCROLL ARROW -->
      <div class="containerStyle" style="text-align: center;">
        <img id="topDownArrow" class="arrowStyle" src="./images/arrow2.png" alt="Arrow Down" />
      </div>


<!-- YOUTUBE -->
  <div class="row containerStyle" style="position: relative; margin-bottom: -50px;">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="badge badge-pill pillStyle">
      <span  class="ytImage">
        <span class="g-ytsubscribe text-left" data-channel="xyz" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></span>
      </span>
        <a href="#" class="viewAll">VIEW ALL <span class="vaArrow">&rarr;</span></a>
      </div>
      <div id="youtubeWrap" class="youtubeWrap">
        <p id="youtubeLabel">ORIGINAL CHOREOGRAPHY<br /> <span id="subytLabel">by: XYZ <br />Artist Ft. Another Artist</span></p>
        <img src="./images/rip2.png" class="ytimageStyle" />
        <div id="arrowLink" class="iframeWrapper">
          <iframe src="#" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is my code. I use jQuery to move down the page. The link to the script is at the bottom of the page and enclosed by:

```
$(function() {});

//smooth scroll from top to article/youtube
  $('#topDownArrow').on('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('#arrowLink').scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  });
```

It seemed to be working fine for a while, but now its hit and miss. Often when you initially load the page it might work the first time you click it. Sometimes it will scroll down slightly then stop. Other times it won't work at all. I'm stumped because it did work at one point and I haven't changed much having to do with this code or markup specifically.

Comment: Having this same problem now in Chrome. A couple of people mention it here too: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/8nv05q/scrollintoview_not_going_to_the_right_place/

Answer (score 0):

After a long tireless search I was able to find a solution that works well for this problem. I'm still not entirely sure why my question version above only works part of the time, but perhaps one day I'll figure it out.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if( target.length ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
  });
```

This solution applies the scrolling animation to any link that links to an id on the page. It's better than what I wanted originally.